# Неправильный вывод суммы матриц С++

Tags: c++, вывод, матрицы

Начал повторять C++ и возникла проблема при суммировании матриц, что вывод 2-х матриц А и В нормальный, а при выводе матрицы А+В выходит вот что :

(матрица 2х2, для других также)

```
а11+в11 -842150451
а21+в21 -842150451
```

Тоесть первые столбцы суммирует нормально,а остальные нет
Почему так?

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;


void MatrCreate(int**Arr2d, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            Arr2d[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

}
void MatrOut(int**Arr2d, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {

            cout << Arr2d[i][j] << " ";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
void MatrSum(int**A1, int**B1,int**Sumarr, int n, int m)
{

        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; i<m; i++)
            {
                Sumarr[i][j] = A1[i][j] + B1[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
            {

                cout << Sumarr[i][j] << " ";

            }
            cout << endl;
        }

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int m;

    cout << " please input n:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << " please input m: " << endl;
    cin >> m;

    int **Arr = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        Arr[i] = new int[n];
    }
    MatrCreate(Arr, n, m);
    MatrOut(Arr, n, m);

    int **Barr = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        Barr[i] = new int[n];
    }
    cout << "____________________" << endl;
    MatrCreate(Barr, n, m);
    MatrOut(Barr, n, m);
    cout << "____________________" << endl;
    cout << " Sum of Matrices:" << endl;
    int **Sumarr = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            Sumarr[i] = new int[n];
        }
        MatrSum(Arr, Barr,Sumarr, n, m);

        delete []Arr; 
        delete []Barr;
        delete []Sumarr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Код написан неряшливо и содержит массу опечаток из-за банальной лени и невнимательности. Опечатки, сделанные по лени и невнимательности, вы должны искать в своем коде самостоятельно, а не просить кого-то делать за вас вашу работу.

Comment: @AnT, никто не должен делать за меня мою работу, но спасибо за указание на цикл где я сделал ошибку. Достаточно было бы просто указать на опечатки, их исправление не есть огромной проблемой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы как будто собираетесь работать с матрицами `n x m`, но выделение памяти везде делаете с размером `n`, при этом почему то выполняя цикл только до `m`

   ```
   int **Arr = new int*[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
       Arr[i] = new int[n];
   }
   ```

   То есть фактически вы выделяете память для матрицы `m x n`. А далее доступаетесь к ней, как к `n x m`. Получается вылет за пределы массива со типичными последствиями.

   Почему цикл только до `m`? Почему всегда выделяется массив размера `n`?
2. Циклы при суммировании матриц

   ```
      for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; i<m; i++)
   ```

   Почему в обоих циклах сравнение и инкремент делается для `i`?
3. Бессмыслицей также является

   ```
   delete Arr, Barr, Sumarr;
   ```

   Что вы пытаетесь этим сделать?

Comment: Собственно какая разница? Лень было код переписывать после предыдущей задачи, да и какая разница когда по умолчанию `m`и `n` равны 0, да и ввести я могу какие угодно значения .

Comment: разве не очевидно? очистить память. И да я пофиксил,  нельзя оказываеться через запятую.

Comment: @Awesome Man: Да, но, во-первых, откуда вы взяли эту идею указать несколько указателей через запятую? Во-вторых, для освобождения массивов используется `delete[]`, а не `delete`. И в третьих, так запросто не получится. Освобождение памяти обычно является зеркальным отражением выделения памяти. Вы выделяли память вызовами `new[]` в цикле? Это значит, что и освобождать память вам придется тоже вызовами `delete[]` в цикле.

Comment: Нуу, я решил попробовать, я же повторяю,( ето про через запятую). А про `delete[]`я не там  скобки поставил( после названия массива), так что оно не сработало, сейчас подправлю . И чесно говоря первый раз слышу про то что очищать память вызовами `delete[] `в цикле надо.Если можна напишите код, я не очень понимаю как получить доступ к строкам.